# I have inherited Invoicing module and added one field in it. How can I fetch the product line from that field and add in invoice field line?

Tags: odoo, odoo-15

I have inherited account.move model and added job_card_id field(many2one) in it, as shown as below :
[image]

Below given is Image of Selected Job Card :

[image]

Below given is code of inherited model :

```
class CustomInvoice(models.Model):
_inherit = "account.move"

job_card_id = fields.Many2one('job.card', string="Job Card", domain="[('customer_id','=',partner_id)]", tracking=True)
```

Below given is code of Job Card Line :

```
class JobCardLine(models.Model):
_name = "job.card.line"

job_card_id = fields.Many2one('job.card', string="Job Card Id", tracking=True)
product_id = fields.Many2one('product.template', string="Product", tracking=True)
quantity = fields.Integer(string="Quantity", tracking=True)
price = fields.Float(
    'Sales Price',
    digits='Product Price')
total = fields.Integer(string='Total', compute='_compute_total', tracking=True,
                       help="This field will be calculated from dob !")
employee_id = fields.Many2one('hr.employee', string="Employee", tracking=True)
```

Now I wanted to add product line of selected job card into Invoice product line automatically when I select the job card.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an onchange method depending on the job_card_id.
In this onchange, you will add a line to `invoice_line_ids`.
This will triggers all the other onchange and compute methods and set ups everything needed.

Here is a small example:

```py
class CustomInvoice(models.Model):
    _inherit = "account.move"

    job_card_id = fields.Many2one('job.card', string="Job Card", domain="[('customer_id','=',partner_id)]", tracking=True)

    @api.onchange('job_card_id')
    def _onchange_job_card_id(self):
        # creates your invoice lines vals according to your values
        invoice_lines_vals = self.job_card_id.get_invoice_line_vals()
        self.write({'invoice_line_ids': [(6, 0, 0)] + [(0, 0, vals) for vals in invoice_lines_vals]})
```

The 6 is a command that will deletes all previous invoice_line and the 0 is a creation command.
[more info on ORM command](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/developer/reference/backend/orm.html#odoo.fields.Command)

Now, you just need to create the `get_invoice_line_vals` method in your `JobCard` class.
It should return a list of vals.
Each vals should be a dict containing some information such as the quantity and the price_unit.

It depends mostly on how you want your data to be calculate.
You just need to return a list like this:

```py
def get_invoice_line_vals(self):
    vals_list = []
    for job_card_line in self.line_ids:
        vals_list.append({
            'price_unit': job_card_line.price_unit,
            'quantity': job_card_line.quantity
        })
    return vals_list
```

Comment: I am getting error of : 'job.card' object has no attribute 'line_ids'

Comment: can u reply please ??

Comment: > I am getting error of : 'job.card' object has no attribute 'line_ids'
This means you are writing on job.card.
Shouldn't you be doing that on the invoice instead?

Comment: Okay I tried in invoice but now it gives error : 'job.card' object has no attribute 'get_invoice_line_vals'

Comment: I put line_ids but you have to put the property that is the one2Many between job card and job card lines